# Collapse navbar toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a question and that is about my navbar collapse in html. i currently use

http://pastebin.com/s92VvJr6

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="container"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      <script>
      
$(function() {
    $('.nav a').on('click', function(){ 
        if($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') !='none'){
            $(".navbar-toggle").trigger( "click" );
        }
    });
});

      </script>
      <img klass="crab" src="images/crab.png" height="50" width="50">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Restaurang MaxLax</a> </div>
    
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="menu-collapsed">
   <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#home" onClick="gaq.push(('_trackPageview', 'home'))" class="link">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu" onClick="gaq.push(('_trackPageview', 'menu'))" class="link">MENU</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gallery" onClick="gaq.push(('_trackPageview', 'gallery'))" class="link">GALLERY</a>
        <li><a href="#contact" onClick="gaq.push(('_trackPageview', 'contact'))" class="link">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid --> 
</nav>
```

(i don't know how to paste it in here, im new)

when the page goes to 765px width it shows the bar icon. problem is that i can't click on it to toggle down some menus. so my question leads to

Q: How do i write the script so it works will with the code.

would also be great if you can make it for me :) hehe

Mvh Max

Comment: Questions asking for code to be written for you aren't on-topic for this site. I'll give you a free pass since you're new, but I'm just warning you, other users are likely to downvote this question because of the lack of research and effort.

Answer (score 0):

So you are using a boostrap navbar without calling the bootstrap js file or the css file for that matter? At least I am not seeing it in your code, and the bootstrap js file should be called directly after the jquery call. Link those two files in from bootstrap and you should have no issue toggling the navbar.

Also as stated this isnt some freelance site that we will just make your code for you. This is a site for you to learn what it is you are doing. If I were you I would edit out that statement pronto or you risk a flurry of downvotes and having the question removed